# Eclipse JavaFX plugin disable validation for web css

Tags: eclipse, javafx, efxclipse

I am using e(fx)clipse plugin for eclipse for my JavaFX project and I have some web css in the resources folder along with JavaFX styles. The issue is all the web css properties are underlined in the editor with a **unknown property** warning.

I have tried navigating through the xtext settings but I couldn't find a solution.

How can I exclude this file from validation?